# Node Js getting an issue while executing for loop

Tags: node.js

I am using node js to develop my application. In controller i used a for loop and then wrote some code, but in for loop i am executing a query. So before that query completely executed once the code after for loop executing. See below for example.

```
var commcount = [];
      for (var j = 0, len = exlist.length; j < len; j++) {  
        console.log('exlist[j].id '+exlist[j].id);
        ExModel.find({EXModel_ID:exlist[j].id, VALUE: {'$ne':''}},{_id:0}, {sort: {CREATION_DATE: -1}}, function(err1, examplist) {
        if (err1) {
            console.log('sub error '+err1);
                commcount.push(0);
        } else {
            console.log('examplist.length '+examplist.length);
                commcount.push(examplist.length);
            }
        });
       }
       console.log('commcount length '+commcount.length);
```

In above code let us assume exlist.length is 5 so, for loop will be executed for 5 times. In the output console, First exlist[j].id value displaying all 5 times then  commcount length value displaying as 0 then only examplist.length value diplaying. So before query executed the for loop for other statements and statements after for loop are being executed. Please help me to solve this. I want the length of result list of query in for loop to be stored in array and want to display those array values after for loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know that you are calling asynchronous function, whatever the result you are getting is correct, The asynchronous function will run in separate thread, we can not guarantee the out put. Your code is similar to the below code, Let's run the below code

```
function run(){
 console.log("d");
 setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("a");
  setTimeout(function(){
   console.log("b");
  });
 });
 console.log("c");
}
```

The output will be `d c a b`.

Comment: Output will be `d c a b`

Comment: Yes you are right! Sorry! while typing I made a mistake.